# JSON query not working

Tags: ios, json, xcode, parsing, swift

I have JSON data coming into my swift app. I want to create a query which I did but the array comes back as nil. Here is my code below:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var RandomQuoteLabel: UITextField!

var bytes: NSMutableData?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "https://www.kimonolabs.com/api/1vldybe0?apikey=iFotcJDm95fB6Ua7XiZRDZA0jl3uYWuc")!)
    let loader = NSURLConnection(request: request, delegate: self, startImmediately: true)
}

    func connection(connection: NSURLConnection!, didReceiveData conData: NSData!) {
            self.bytes?.appendData(conData)
    }

    func connection(didReceiveResponse: NSURLConnection!, didReceiveResponse response: NSURLResponse!) {
            self.bytes = NSMutableData()
}

        func connectionDidFinishLoading(connection: NSURLConnection!) {
            let jsonresult:NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(self.bytes!, options: nil, error: nil) as NSDictionary
            println(jsonresult)

//This is where the app crashes
            let results: NSArray = jsonresult["collection1"] as NSArray
            println(results)
            for item in results {
                var quote:String = item["quote"] as String
                println("\(quote)")
            }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



}
```

Why does the query not work. All suggestions welcomed.

Comment: `collection1` is an object of `jsonresult["results"]`, not a "direct" one from `jsonresult`, you're missing a level => `let results: NSArray = jsonresult["results"] as NSDictionary` and `let collection1: NSArray = results["collection1"] as NSArray`

Comment: It says NSDictionary is not convertible to NSArray.

Comment: Sorry, my bad I messds up the copy/paste. `let results: NSDictionary = ...` the point was that you missed a level.

Comment: Ok Thanks. I though that was the case. :) How can I up vote you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [larme](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1801544/larme)'s suggestion Correct your code with below changes.

```
let results: NSDictionary = jsonresult["results"] as NSDictionary

let collection1: NSArray = results["collection1"] as NSArray

println(collection1)
for item in collection1 {
    var quote:String = item["quote"] as String
    println("\(quote)")
}
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68724/discussion-between-naeem-and-nathan-schafer).